# Jenkins giving JAVA.io.IOException while installing plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, java-io, ioexception

I have installed latest version of Jenkins (2.19.1) on my server as windows service, when I am trying to install Plugins like SVN, MSBuild etc it is giving me error Java.io.IOException. Any idea what is this issue about and how can we solve this?

Thanks in advance!!